# Stopping user input after certain entry?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a very simple Java problem where I need to stop taking in data after a certain user value is entered. The user can still enter data after the value is entered, but once the value is entered, the output should not include that value or any data following that value. Also, I was trying to discount negative entries from being counted, but to no avail. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Please input any number, up to 10 entries. "
                + "Enter -1 to exit: ");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] input_array = new int[10];
        int numOfEntries = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < input_array.length; i++)
        {
            input_array[i] = read.nextInt();
            numOfEntries++;
            //only positive numbers
            if(input_array[i] >= 100 || input_array[i] < 0)
            { 
                if(input_array[i] == 77) //certain value
                { 
                    //entries before 77 is entered become the new array
                    numOfEntries = i;
                    int[] new_array = new int[numOfEntries];
                    for (int j = 0; j < numOfEntries; j++)
                    {
                        new_array[j] = input_array[i];
                    }
                    System.out.print(new_array[numOfEntries] + " ");
                }               
                if(input_array[i] == -1) //exit loop
                {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive 
                number that is less than 100.");
            }
        }   

        //final result
        System.out.println("Your entries are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfEntries; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(input_array[i] + " ");
        }
```

Comment: How can a number which is either larger than 100 or smaller than 0 also be equal to 77?

Comment: do not increment or assign to the input_array unless it passes the checks

Answer (score 0):

You should check like this to make sure everything correctly passes the conditions

```
//all this goes inside the for loop
    String input = read.nextInt();
    if (input == -1)
        break;
    if (input > 0)//is it negative? 
    {
        if (input < 100)//is it greater than 100?
        {
           if (input == 77)//is it 77?
           {
               //your code
           } 
           else//this will run when all conditions are passed
             input_array[i] = input; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a separate array,add into the initial array,only if it is a valid value.Check the below code,have made few modifications:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        {
            System.out.println("Please input any number, up to 10 entries. " + "Enter -1 to exit: ");
            Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] input_array = new int[10];
            int numOfEntries = 0;
            int entry = 0, status = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < input_array.length; i++) {
                entry = read.nextInt();
                // only positive numbers
                if (entry < 100 && entry >= 0) {
                    if (entry == 77) // certain value,change the value of 'status' here 
                    {
                        status = 1;
                    }
                    if (status == 0) //if 'status' is not reset,then add the entry to array.
                    {
                        input_array[numOfEntries++] = entry;
                    }

                }  else if (entry == -1) // exit loop
                {
                    break;
                }else {//for negative and values which are greater than 100.
                    System.out.println("Please enter a positive number that is less than 100.");
                }
            }

            // final result
            System.out.println("Your entries are: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfEntries; i++) {
                System.out.print(input_array[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add another array if you are not going to use it, So I have removed it and made some modification in your code. Please check the below code. Go through the comments. Hope you will understand.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please input any number, up to 10 entries. "
                + "Enter -1 to exit: ");

        int[] input_array = new int[10]; //Input array - size 10
        int input = 0; // input variable
        boolean isInput77 = false; //Check input is 77 (certain value)
        int numOfEntries = 0; // Number of entries that passes your conditions
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            input = read.nextInt(); // input value assign to "input" variables 
            if (input == -1){  // input is -1 break
                break;
            } else if (input == 77){ // input is 77 isInput77 is true
                isInput77 = true;
            } else if (!isInput77 && input < 100 && input >= 0) { // isInput77 is false and input is positive number that is less than 100 add to input_array
                input_array[numOfEntries] = input;
                numOfEntries++;
            } else if(input >= 100 || input < -1){ // input is negative or greater than or equal to 100 
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number that is less than 100.");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Your entries are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfEntries; i++) { // Print only valuable entries
            System.out.print(input_array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```